# Batch size and steps per epoch

Tags: keras, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, training

My data size is 6011, which is a prime number, and therefore, the only batch size number that divides this data evenly is either 1 or 6011. However, I need the batch size to be 32, which means that the `steps_per_epoch` with being equal to ${6011 \over 32} = 187.84$.

My question is what will happen to the last step of training (step number 188) if I set the `steps_per_epoch` to $188$? Will it contain the remaining samples which are $6011-(187*32)= 27$ samples?

Comment: Yes I think so. What framework are you using?

Comment: @ashutoshsingh keras

Comment: Then it should work